# Computer stuck on system initializing

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building

I've just built a new PC. However, when I turn the PC it gets stuck on a screen that says system initializing in the bottom left corner and the POST will not start. How can I fix this? I think that it is an issue with the RAM but I am unsure. I am using an ASRockRack E3C224d2I with Crucial Ballistix sport 16 gb. [Here are the parts I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxV8k.png)

Comment: Try taking out the RAM, and putting in a single RAM stick that is known to work correctly.  Beware that some motherboards expect single sticks in slot 1, some don't mind which slot.

Comment: I tried using only one ram stick, but all that did was cause my computer to get stuck on a screen that said "Waiting for BMC Initializing"

Comment: Crucially, was the RAM known working from another PC?  This may be worth contacting ASRock support.